# Random date in calculated columns

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

How can i have a random date in calculated columns ?

I tried RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2015;1;1);DATE(2017;4;4)) which works in Excel, but not in Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Because SharePoint only does the simple functions:

- http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

For random values read:

- http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.nl/2016/11/creating-random-numbers-in-sharepoint.html